# Meaning of ‘Lernfeldübergreifend’

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I was searching for the meaning of **Lernfeldübergreifende** or **Lernfeldübergreifende Fachgebiet** but I didn’t find any reliable translation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site and visit the [ħelp] for any questions about it that may remain. Your question is dangerously close to a simple translation request which would be discouraged on this site. I’m not sure if it will get closed, just saying it *may.* You may want to add further research you did just in case.

Comment: Above comment should read [help]. I have no idea how the h-bar got in there ^^'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Lernfeld

lernen (Verb) = to learn
Feld (Substantiv) = field, area, orbit, ...

this gives:
Lernfeld (Substantiv) = learning orbit, area of learning, but very often just *lernfeld* (as german loanword)

---

### übergreifen, übergreifend

über (Präposition) = over
greifen (Verb) = to grab
greifend (Adjektiv oder Verb, Partizip Präsens) = grabbing

übergreifen (Verb) = literally *to grab over*, but in fact means *to overlap*
übergreifend (Adjektiv oder Verb, PP) = overlapping, across, overall, comprehensive

---

### lernfeldübergreifend

lernfeldübergreifend (Adjektiv o.V.PP) = lapping over learning orbits, going across areas of learning

---

### Fachgebiet

Fach (Substantiv) has many meanings. Here: subject (of education)
Gebiet (Substantiv) = area, reagion

Fachgebiet (Substantiv) is just a synonym of *Fach*, so *Fachgebiet* = subject (of education)

---

### all together

> lernfeldübergreifendes Fachgebiet = A subject of education that overlaps some learning orbits.

I guess you can say it shorter:

> A comprehensive subject.

Answer (score 2):

Given the academic context, I'd translate it as

> Interdisciplinary subject

Answer (score 1):

**Lernfeldübergreifende Fachgebiet** means, it is a **subject which includes an overall learning field**

Comment: Yeah, Id say so. My bad. Hey, sorry if some thing stay unclear. Im did my best to help translate it. :/

Comment: Julind, feel free to edit your own answer. I That way it might even be possible that the downvote gets removed (provided the person who downvoted notices the edit) Oh, and do take the [tour] and visit the [help] center